# How to test MaterialStateProperty values?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I have a button with a specific elevation, set as an argument:

```dart
        child: ElevatedButton(
          key: const Key('MyButton'),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('My Button'),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(2.0),
              ),
            ), ...
```

I would like to test the elevation value. The snippet I've wrote is below:

```dart
      final button = tester
          .widget<ElevatedButton>(find.byKey(Key('NewSessionsElevatedButton')));
      expect(button.style.elevation, MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(2.0));
```

However, the exception below is raised in the test, telling both values are equal, but it breaks anyway:

```bash
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: _MaterialStatePropertyAll<double>:<MaterialStateProperty.all(2.0)>
  Actual: _MaterialStatePropertyAll<double>:<MaterialStateProperty.all(2.0)>
```

I've read the [tests](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/87804363e4b5c9150eb19869a14319a622b79bc8/packages/flutter/test/material/material_state_property_test.dart) for this class in the repository, but they are not clear. How can I test `MaterialStateProperty` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just got hit by this issue myself.

For your specific test, this would be the code:

```
final button = tester.widget<ElevatedButton(find.byKey(Key('MyButton')));
final elevation = button.style!.elevation;

expect(elevation!.resolve(<MaterialState>{}), 2.0);
expect(elevation.resolve(<MaterialState>{MaterialState.hovered}), 2.0);
expect(elevation.resolve(<MaterialState>{MaterialState.focused}), 2.0);
expect(elevation.resolve(<MaterialState>{MaterialState.pressed}), 2.0);
expect(elevation.resolve(<MaterialState>{MaterialState.dragged}), 2.0);
expect(elevation.resolve(<MaterialState>{MaterialState.selected}), 2.0);
expect(elevation.resolve(<MaterialState>{MaterialState.disabled}), 2.0);
expect(elevation.resolve(<MaterialState>{MaterialState.error}), 2.0);
```

You need use [resolve](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialStateProperty/resolve.html) in order to retrieve the exact state for which to test.
The properties of the ButtonStyles are sets, so you need to get the value for each state you want to test.

Hope it helped.